# How do I extend nonclient area into a window thinner than 16 pixels?

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-8.1

I'm working on a project that requires me to draw a thin line horizontally across the screen and drag it vertically. To add a bit of flair I'm trying to add the DWM glass effect to the window so that it will match window boders in Windows 7 and 8 (though I know I won't get transparency in Windows 8).

I've got the line drawn by creating a child window with the non client area extended into the client area using the [sheet of glass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) trick with DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea like this:

```
MARGINS margins = { -1, -1, -1, -1 };
DwmEnableComposition(DWM_EC_ENABLECOMPOSITION);
DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(DIV_HWND, &margins);
```

And I create the window like this:

```
HWND DIV_HWND = CreateWindow(DIV_NAME,
    NULL,
    WS_VISIBLE,
    0, 0, mon_info.rcWork.right, mon_info.rcWork.top + 3,
    top->hwnd, NULL,
    hInstance, NULL);
```

And the window class like this:

```
const wchar_t DIV_NAME[] = L"DIV";

WNDCLASS DIV = {};
DIV.lpfnWndProc = DIV_PROC;
DIV.hInstance = hInstance;
DIV.lpszClassName = DIV_NAME;
DIV.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_SIZEALL);

RegisterClass(&DIV);
```

I've gotten the window down to a width of 16 pixels with all the nice borders and drop shadow effects I expect to see around a windows border by handling the WM_GETMINMAXINFO message and returning 2 as the ptMinTrackSize.x and y but I can't seem to get it smaller than that.

I can get a "glassy" window by using DwmEnableBlurBehindWindow on a region I set with SetWindowRgn but the color is that of a background window even when it is in focus. Additionally I miss the slight drop shadow and border.

It seems like I might be hitting the size restriction due to border sizes since each border is 8 pixels wide.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What actually happens when you do go below 16 pixels?

Comment: The window shows up as 16 pixels high. I should have noted that the window is not surrounded by a border as I have handled the WM_NCCALCSIZE to return 0, so my window sizing happens on creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my answer so I'll leave it here on the off chance someone else needs it. All I had to do was call `DwmSetWindowAttribute(hwmd, DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY, DWMNCRP_ENABLED, sizeof(int));` to ensure the DWM rendering policy was not based on the window style. This allowed me to use a WS_POPUP window to get the size I wanted with a nicely glass filled interior.

There are a few bugs here:

1. There is a strange shadow along the top and bottom if the Y dimension of the window is smaller than 16px.
2. On Vista\7 the rounded window edges give the window a strange oval-like shape.